# Python: to print random 5 scrapes

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have a problem with a school project, that says i should make a scraper program with beautifulSoup that will be a weeding surprise and will print out random 5 quotes out of the page they gave me ....well I came to a logic how to scrape the data out of the site and it scrapes the quotes but it doesn't return 5 of them but all of them.....i tried with counter but no luck could you help me out please?

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


topic_url = 'http://quotes.yourdictionary.com/theme/marriage/'
topic_html = urllib.urlopen(topic_url).read()
topic_soup = BeautifulSoup(topic_html)


quotes = topic_soup.findAll('p', attrs={'class': 'quoteContent'})


for quote in quotes:

    print quote.text + ("\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have all the quotes stored in the `quotes` variable. You can select 5 random ones from that collection with the `random` module:

```
import random

five_quotes = random.sample(set(quotes), 5)
for quote in five_quotes:
    print(quote.text + "\n")
```

Comment: I hope you won't get duplicate items.

Comment: @swatchai I updated my answer, converting `quotes` to a set to remove duplicates. `random.sample()` already returns unique elements according to their indices alone so that was the only change required. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the limit parameter to 5 as below

```
quotes = topic_soup.findAll('p', limit=5, attrs={'class': 'quoteContent'})
```